# using Start pause action in tableview cell.if i select start it is showing pause and scroll the table again showing start in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return pavanobjets.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellidentifier = @"Cell";

    Cell = (myCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];
    if (Cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevel = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id curretobj in topLevel) { 
            if ([curretobj isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {    
                Cell = (myCell *)curretobj;
                break;
            }
        }

        Cell.lblData.text = [pavanobjets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [Cell.btnStart addTarget:self action:@selector(likeEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        // Cell.btnStart.tag=indexPath.row;  
    }
    return Cell;
}
```

Action

```
- (void)likeEvent:(UIButton *)sender
{  
    UIButton *likeButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    if (likeButton.isSelected) {
        [likeButton  setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"start.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [likeButton  setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    }
    [likeButton  setSelected:!likeButton.isSelected];
    NSLog(@"like:%d",likeButton.isSelected);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reload that particular cell after you set the image.

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *)indexPaths 
                  withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```

Use this method to reload the cell

```
  - (void)likeEvent:(UIButton *)sender {
            NSInteger row = your desired row
            NSInteger section = your desired section

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] indexPathForItem:row section:section];
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] 
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]
        }
```